# Magento 2 Frontend Controller that does not register customer URL

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2 I am attempting to setup a controller I can retrieve after page load via Ajax that does not register as a URL in the admin panel for "Customers>Now Online"

I have a route.xml setup as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="..
/../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="mymodule" frontName="mymodule">
            <module name="Testing_Mymodule" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

And a controller such as:

```
namespace Testing\Mymodule\Controller\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{


    public function execute()
    {
        $jsonData = json_encode(array('test1', 'test2', 'test3'));
        $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
        $this->getResponse()->setBody($jsonData);
    }
}
```

This results in a json result of the json array. Now if one checks the "Customers>Now Online" It shows the controller as the last URL visited. Is there a way to access this controller without registering the URL.

Comment: do you have a `module.xml` in your module? Did you clear the cache? How are you calling your url?

Comment: Marius, yes the module is appearing and I can connect to the controller. What I am trying to achieve is a controller that I can connect to via Ajax that doesn't change the customers "Now Online" URL

Comment: I can access the controller via the domain.com/mymodule and it returns that json array. However, it is registering this as the last visited page for the customer in the "Customers>Now Online" report

Answer (score 1):

I took a look through the `\Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor` model and it seams that you can skip the loging for certain user agents and for certain modules. (check the `initByRequest` method).
By the looks of the method `isModuleIgnored`, the one that checks if a module should be skipped you may be able to ignore the logging for your module by adding this, in the `di.xml` of your module:

```
<type name="Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="ignores" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="the_route_name_of_your_module" xsi:type="bool">true</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

But I didn't test it.